# Cannot retrieve error message using Symfony HttpClient if the response is not "ok"

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-http-client

I use Symfony HttpClient to call an external API. When the status code is 200 I can use `getContent()` method to retrieve the API response. If the API response is 400, a `ClientException` is thrown, and I cannot get the external API message.

```
$httpClient = HttpClient::create();
$response = $httpClient->request($method, $url);
if (200 !== $response->getStatusCode()) {
    $apiResponse['statusCode'] = $response->getStatusCode();
    $httpInfo = $response->getInfo();
    $content = $response->getContent(); //this throws ClientException
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use

```
$response->getContent(false)
```

to get the response and not an error thrown.

Explanation from Code:

```
    public function getContent(bool $throw = true): string
```

Note that you lose a bit of the very meaningful wrapping functionality HttpClient provides you here.

Comment: could you please clarify which meaningful wrapping functionality ypu mean here? Thank you

Comment: check what you can do with Response in the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_client.html#processing-responses). If you just expect a string nothing special would be required, but checkout [exception handling](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_client.html#handling-exceptions)