# Http Request doesn't catch all errors

Tags: php, symfony, get, httprequest

I am currently working on a project in symfony where my database has alot of links stored in it. With a press of a button I want to validate all the links with a http request.

What I have so far is working fine for most cases:

I have a service that sends the request and returns the status code

```
    public function validateUrl($query) 
    {
        $response = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            $query
        );

        $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();

        return $statusCode;
    }
```

And in the validate function that calls the service I have this

```
public function validateAll(UrlValidatorService $urlValidatorService)
    {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $referrer = $request->query->get('referrer');

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Url::class);
        $longUrls = $repository->findBy([], ['id' => 'ASC']);
        
        foreach($longUrls as $urlEntity)
        {
            $url = $urlEntity->getLongUrl();
            $statusCode = $urlValidatorService->validateUrl($url);
            $datestring = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            if($statusCode == 200) 
            {
                $urlEntity->setValidStatus('valid');
                $urlEntity->setValidDate(new \DateTime($datestring));
            }

            if($statusCode >= 300)
            {
                $urlEntity->setValidStatus('invalid');
                $urlEntity->setValidDate(new \DateTime($datestring));
            }

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($urlEntity);
            $entityManager->flush(); 
        }

        return $this->redirect($referrer);
    }
```

As I said this works in most cases but theres some errors that this for some reason doesn't catch and I don't know how to solve it. Any help is appreciated

Example of error it can't catch:
[Example Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi1Sn.png)

Comment: please have a look here whether this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288142/cannot-retrieve-error-message-using-symfony-httpclient.

Comment: The host name in this particular case does not appear to resolve in the DNS, https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3awww.waters.biz&run=toolpage

Comment: @CBroe yes I know. maybe I should've clarified. The tool I'm working on checks what statuscode the request sends back and then in the database it sets the date when the link was checked if its valid or not and it also puts the status (valid/invalid). The problem is on that link even though it should be invalid it throws a smfony exception instead of setting it as invalid

Comment: That’s because the error happens, before it even gets to the part where you check on the status code. The request could not be made to begin with, so where do you expect a status code to even come from now …? You’ll need to go and catch the exception first of all. And when you caught one, make your `validateUrl` method return null or false – something that can be distinguished from an actual status code outside of the method.

Comment: @LBA no even when I do getContent(false) it still throws the errors even though the solutions explanation seems to be exactly what I need

Comment: @CBroe https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34281 catching it doesn't seem to work. I don't quite understand the solution to this though so maybe you can explain to me what he means?

Comment: Does https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#handling-exceptions help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. Even though https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34281 states that catching the errors doesn't work because the responses are lazy I was able to catch them like this:

```
    public function validateUrl($query) 
    {
        try{
            $response = $this->client->request('GET', $query, ['timeout' => 5]);

            $response->getContent(false);
            $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        }
        catch (HttpExceptionInterface $e) {    
            $statusCode = '404';
        }
        // Exceptions like Timeout
        catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
            $statusCode = '404';
        }
        
        return $statusCode;
    }
```